# Ignore Vendor Imports when Bundling w/ Webpack and Typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack, es6-modules

When using Webpack I wan't to ignore 3rd party libs like angular because I will be providing them myself.

I have the following entry index.ts:

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
angular
  .module('myapp', [
    'ui.router'
  ]);
```

Now this includes the entire angular library in my bundle which I don't want.

If I take away the import and rely on typings for angular then I get the following error:

error TS2686: 'angular' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding angular to the `externals` section in my webpack config prevents the library from actually being bundled.